# Merging two perfect binary heaps?

Tags: java, data-structures, merge, binary-heap

I've been stuck on a question for a while and was wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction:

> Suppose binary heaps are represented using a pointer-based tree representation instead of an array. Consider the problem of merging binary heap LHS with RHS. Assume both heaps are full complete trees, containing (2^L - 1) and (2^R -1) nodes, respectively.
>   Give two O(log N) algorithms to merge the two heaps, one if L = R and one if |L - R| = 1.

This is a homework problem, I just need to be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Does the LHS tree need to start on the left, or is this just a name for convenience?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint for L=R: pretend you've just removed the root. Let me know if you need more.

Comment: This is a good hint. What I can't figure out is, what is the prof. getting at with the |L-R| = 1? Seems like the algorithm that is the result of your hint would work in that case as well.

Comment: Think about the properties of an array-based heap, and how the algorithm hinted at would violate some of these properties if |L-R|=1. Actually, it's not just array-based heaps; think about the shape property.

Comment: I am not able to get this hint. Please explain further.